# Mismatch in the mass dimensions of the dilaton field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, string-theory, dimensional-analysis, effective-field-theory

In chapter 7 of David Tongs' [string theory lectures](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), the low-energy effective action of string theory is presented, and given by eq.(7.16):

$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa^2_0}\int d^{26}X\sqrt{-G}e^{-2\Phi}\left[R-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}+4\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial^{\mu}\Phi\right].\tag{7.16}$$

If we make a dimensional analysis in natural units of mass $M$ for the first term, we will see that because that
$$ds^2=G_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu $$
and $$\left[ds^2\right]=M^{-2}$$
thus
$$\left[G_{\mu\nu}\right]=M^0 \Rightarrow \left[\sqrt{-G}\right]=M^0 .$$
The gravitational constant $\kappa^2_0$ is given in terms of string length $l_s$ thus:
$$\kappa^2_0 \sim l_s^{24}\Rightarrow \left[\kappa^2_0\right]=M^{-24}$$

In many sources, the mass dimension of a Ricci scalar is given by:
$$\left[R\right]=M^2$$
and
$$\left[d^{26}X\right]=M^{-26}.$$
So by the basic demand that the action is dimensionless:
$$\left[S\right]=M^0$$

we infer that:
$$\left[e^{-2\Phi}\right]=M^0.$$

Now, looking at the third term in the effective action, recall that
$$\left[\partial_{\mu}\right ]=\left[\partial^{\mu}\right]=M^1.$$
Thus we infer that:
$$\left[\Phi\right]=M^0$$
but we know that $\Phi$ is a massless spinless scalar field, and the mass dimensions of a scalar field in general $D$ spacetime dimensions, is given by:
$$\left[\Phi\right]=M^{\frac{D-2}{2}}.$$
In our case $D=26$ and thus we expect:
$$\left[\Phi\right]=M^{12}.$$
what is the source of this mismatch?
and if there is a real mismatch, why don't we scale it with $\alpha'=l_s^2$
to fit the scalar field dimensions so eventually, the action will take the form:
$$S = \frac{1}{2\kappa^2_0}\int d^{26}X\sqrt{-G}e^{-2(\alpha')^{6}\Phi}\left[R-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}+4(\alpha')^{12}\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial^{\mu}\Phi\right] $$
instead?

Comment: Well, OP has correctly shown that the dilaton $\Phi$ in the string frame action (7.16) is dimensionless, and it does not have the standard engineering dimension of a scalar field.

Comment: @Qmechanic I showed it on the target space picture not in the worldsheet picture